# Prisma graphql error on signUp mutation

Tags: javascript, graphql, prisma

I tried to do a signup mutation in the playground but I am getting an error which I cannot understand, tried a lot of ways to fix it like adding an authorisation header by getting a token from prisma token also, quite stuck..

[image]

Comment: Hey, this looks related to this issue: https://github.com/graphcool/graphql-yoga/issues/162 Can you confirm this? :)

Comment: seems like it, let me try rolling back..thanks @marktani

Comment: yup roll back works @marktani

Answer (score 10):

That error occurs if you have two different versions of `graphql` in your entire dependency tree.

Your dependencies and dev dependencies for `package.json` need to use the same version of `graphql`, and all those dependencies need to have `graphql` as their peer dependency, like this:

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "graphql": "^0.11.0 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0"
  }
```

Note that in your own `package.json`, you don't need the peer dependency. Here's an example of dependencies in your `package.json` that fulfill the requirements I mentioned above:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "graphql-yoga": "1.4.3",
    "prisma-binding": "1.5.16"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "graphql-cli": "2.15.8",
    "prisma": "1.3.3"
  }
```

I copied the dependencies from [here](https://github.com/graphql-boilerplates/typescript-graphql-server/blob/c1ffe6899abc0f6a34c3306bf5161ccd3175de44/advanced/package.json).

Update your `package.json` to the above dependencies , then `rm -rf node_modules yarn.lock` and `npm install` or `yarn`.